# React Native trying to pass coords to Polyline getting error: NSNumber cannot be converted to NSDictionary

Tags: javascript, react-native

so I am trying to pass coords from BackgroundGeolocation.getLocations() method.
So when I pass coords I am getting this error:
**JSON value '-122.02235491' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSDictionary**

I tried to look at the Polyline docs and can't figure out what should I change in my coordArray so Polyline would accept it?

The variable location structure is this:
[https://transistorsoft.github.io/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/interfaces/*cordova_background_geolocation_lt*.location.html](https://transistorsoft.github.io/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/interfaces/_cordova_background_geolocation_lt_.location.html)

Thanks in advance!

```
if(this.state.locations && this.state.locations.length > 0){
      this.state.locations.map((location,index) => {
        console.log(this.state.locations)
        let coordArray = [latitude = parseFloat(location.coords.latitude), longitude= parseFloat(location.coords.longitude)]
        polyline.push(<Polyline key={index} initialRegion={initialRegion} coordinates={coordArray} geodesic />)
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array of numbers, to `coordinates` parameter, effectively having something like (sample coords)
`<Polyline ... coordinates={[-122.0, 88]}>`
Polyline docs say that you've got to have an array of dictionaries in your coordinates, like so:
`<Polyline ... coordinates={[{latitude:-122.0, longitude:88}]}>`
This is basically what causes the error, it takes the first element of your array, which is a number, and tries to convert it to dictionary.
Check https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polyline.md
for details.